# Why was this migration flag declined?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, flagging

This question - [What did Madara mean by "showing our guts"?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/12772/what-did-madara-mean-by-showing-our-guts) - is a question asking about the definition of an english phrase.

Sure, it was found in a manga, but apart from that, it's not really to do with Anime & Manga - just like questions about Japanese that are not relevant to the plot (e.g. https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4111/what-is-the-japanese-symbol-on-the-wall-in-episode-83-of-hunter-x-hunter)

I don't see why questions about English would not fall under the same rules?

Answer (score 3):

This is because the scope of the question was worded to ask about what it meant in context with the anime. So therefore it's on-topic. Though it is a question about the English language, it's more so about the context of the situation in anime, therefore it is on-topic here. If what was simply asked was simply "What does the expression 'show me you guts' mean?" without the Naruto anime as context, it *might* be on-topic for ELL. A good answer to this question would tie the context into it's answer.

The only reason the HxH question was labeled as off-topic, was because it *only* asked for what the kanji meant *in Japanese,* rather than why Netero you see this kanji associated with him, in addition to what it meant.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that neither [ell.se] or [english.se] wanted it.